# Mock a void method

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, junit5, powermockito

//Original method:

```
@Autowired
    private ConversionServiceValidator validator; 

    public CRSConversionResult convertCRS(ConvertCrsVo convertCrsVo) throws Exception {

if (validator.isSameSourceAndTarget(convertCrsVo))
            throw new ValidationException(Constants.BADREQUEST);

        if (convertCrsVo.getPreferredTransforms() != null) {
            List<TransformVo> preferredTransformList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (TransformVo transformVo : convertCrsVo.getPreferredTransforms()) {
                preferredTransformList.add(getPerfByCode(transformVo));
            }
            convertCrsVo.setPreferredTransforms(preferredTransformList);
        }
        convertCrsVo.setSourceCRS(getCrsVoByCode(convertCrsVo.getSourceCRS()));
        convertCrsVo.setTargetCRS(getCrsVoByCode(convertCrsVo.getTargetCRS()));
        convertCrsVo = validator.replaceCoordinates(convertCrsVo);
        logger.info("ShellGeodeticService::convertCRS::Request to GeoCalService convertpoints::" + mapper.writeValueAsString(convertCrsVo));
        ConvertPointsResponse response = geoCalService.convertCRS(convertCrsVo);
        CRSConversionResult result = new CRSConversionResult();
        result.setCriteriaMessage(response.getCriteriaMessage());
        result.setResultPoints(response.getResultPoints());
        result.setTransformName(response.getTransformName());
        result.setTransformDescription(response.getTransformDescription());
        // added schema as per pbi 195298
        List<ConvertedTransformsResult> transformsResults = new ArrayList<>();
        if (response.getTransforms() != null || !response.getTransforms().isEmpty())
            response.getTransforms().stream().forEach(
                    t -> transformsResults.add(new ConvertedTransformsResult().getConvertedTransformsResult(t)));
        result.setTransforms(transformsResults);
        String logmessage=generateLogMessage(result,convertCrsVo);
        logger.info(logmessage);
        validator.isResponseValid(result);
        return result;
}
```

//The testcase for the above method

```
@Test
    public void testconvertCRSJob() throws Exception{
        ConvertCrsVo convertCrsVo = TestDataFactory.getConvertCrsVo();
        CRSConversionResult crsConversionResult = TestDataFactory.getCRSConversionResult();
        ConversionServiceValidator conversionServiceValidatorMock = mock(ConversionServiceValidator.class);
Mockito.when(geoCalService.convertCRS(Mockito.any()))
        .thenReturn(TestDataFactory.getConvertPointsResponse(convertCrsVo));
Mockito.when(validator.replaceCoordinates(convertCrsVo))
        .thenReturn(TestDataFactory.getConvertCrsVo());
Mockito.when(geoCalService.search(Mockito.any(SearchFilter.class)))
        .thenReturn(TestDataFactory.getSearchResultResponseForCRS());
Mockito.when(shellGeodeticService.convertCRS(convertCrsVo))
        .thenReturn(TestDataFactory.getCRSConversionResult());  
shellGeodeticService.convertCRSJob();

        }
```

The error that i am getting is as below:

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.CannotStubVoidMethodWithReturnValue: 
'**isResponseValid**' is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*!
Voids are usually stubbed with Throwables:
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();

---

If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. The method you are trying to stub is *overloaded*. Make sure you are calling the right overloaded version.
2. Somewhere in your test you are stubbing *final methods*. Sorry, Mockito does not verify/stub final methods.
3. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
4. Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

```
at com.shell.geodetic.GeodeticConvertionApiAppTests.testconvertCRSJob(GeodeticConvertionApiAppTests.java:1783)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Can someone help me on how to stub the void method "isResponseValid" ? I tried around 100 combinations that i saw in SOF and nothing worked. Thanks for the help in advance.

*Edit

```
Class ConversionServiceValidator {

    public void isResponseValid(CRSConversionResult response) throws InvalidDataException {

            if (response.getResultPoints().isEmpty() || response.getResultPoints() == null) {
                throw new ValidationException("Request body has incorrect format");
            } else {
                for (Point point : response.getResultPoints()) {
                    if (point.getX().trim().equals("0") || point.getY().trim().equals("0")) {
                        throw new InvalidDataException(400, "Bad Request", "WARNING: Not all points could be converted",
                                response);
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Your test code does not contain any defined behaviour for `validator.isResponseValid`. As `validator` seems to be a mock (which implies that all methods are doing nothing), what is it that you are trying to define?

Comment: @second Sir i have edited as per your suggestion, can you please assist me here.

Comment: I have seen your edit, but it does not answer my question. Your code does not reproduce the error, as there is no attempt to mock `isResponseValid` contained in there. Also I am still not sure what you are trying to do ...

Comment: Also the method you posted is `convertCRS` while in your test you seem to call `shellGeodeticService.convertCRSJob();`. Its also unclear what `shellGeodeticService` is supposed to be. Is it a `mock` or a `spy`?

Comment: 1) there is no attempt to mock isResponseValid: Actually i need to know how to mock the isResponseValid method.

2) Actually it should be shellGeodeticService.convertCRS(); -- sorry for the mistake there

3) Its also unclear what shellGeodeticService is -- It is a  mock
 @InjectMocks
 ShellGeodeticService shellGeodeticService;

4)Also I am still not sure what you are trying to do --- Actually im trying to run test case for shellGeodeticService.convertCRS() and since it calls isResponseValid method internally , i have to mock that also right? so, i need assitance in how to mock it sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is a mock @InjectMocks ShellGeodeticService shellGeodeticService;

`shellGeodeticService` is not a mock. `@InjectMocks` is used for the class under test, where the `mocks` are injected into.

That implies you can not use

```java
Mockito.when(shellGeodeticService.convertCRS(convertCrsVo)) 
       .thenReturn(TestDataFactory.getCRSConversionResult());
```

in your test as only `mocks`(or `spys`) can be used within `Mockito.when`.

---

> Actually im trying to run test case for shellGeodeticService.convertCRS() and since it calls isResponseValid method internally , i have to mock that also right?

No, that is incorrect. If `validator` is a mock every method invocation will do nothing by default. So, unless you want to throw an exception, you do not need to define anything.

---

As your question lacks some details, I assume a complete version of your test could be similiar to this:

```java
@InjectMocks
ShellGeodeticService shellGeodeticService;

@Mock
ConversionServiceValidator validator;

@Mock
... geoCalService; // some unknown class

@Test
public void testconvertCRSJob() throws Exception{

    ConvertCrsVo convertCrsVo = TestDataFactory.getConvertCrsVo();

    // Note sure whether this is correct by your logic as there is no `replacement` happening.
    Mockito.when(validator.replaceCoordinates(convertCrsVo)).thenReturn(convertCrsVo);

    Mockito.when(geoCalService.convertCRS(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(TestDataFactory.getConvertPointsResponse(convertCrsVo));

    CRSConversionResult result = shellGeodeticService.convertCRS();

    // do some assertions on the result
}
```

As `validator` is a mock:

- `validator.isSameSourceAndTarget(convertCrsVo)` returns `false` be default
- `validator.isResponseValid( ... )` does nothing by default

As you did not add the methods `getCrsVoByCode`, `getPerfByCode` and `generateLogMessage` take note that if there are any further interactions with the mocked objects you'll need to add them.
(eg.: a call to `geoCalService.search` is not visible in your test code, so I removed the behaviour definition from the test displayed above)